# Staggered Starts

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

In races in which racers go around at least one turn of a curved track, the starting positions for each racer are staggered, so that each racer travels the same distance around the track (otherwise, the racer in the innermost lane would have a huge advantage).

Given the lengths of the major and minor axes (or semi-major and semi-minor, if you'd prefer) of an elliptical track and the number of lanes in the track, output the distances from the innermost lane's starting point that each lane should be staggered.

### Specifications

- Each lane is an ellipse with semi-major axes 5 units longer than the next-shortest lane. For simplicity, assume that the lanes have 0 width.
- The innermost lane always starts at 0, and every other starting point is a positive integer greater than or equal to the previous starting point.
- Input and output may be in any convenient and reasonable format.
- The inputs will always be integers.
- You must calculate the circumference of the track to within 0.01 units of the actual value.
- Outputs are to be rounded down to the nearest integer (floored).
- The finish line is the starting point for the innermost racer. There is only one lap in the race.
- The lengths of the axes are measured using the innermost lane of the track.
- Outputting the 0 for the innermost lane's offset is optional.

### Test Cases

Format: `a, b, n -> <list of offsets, excluding innermost lane>`

```
20, 10, 5 -> 30, 61, 92, 124
5, 5, 2 -> 31
15, 40, 7 -> 29, 60, 91, 121, 152, 183
35, 40, 4 -> 31, 62, 94
```

These test cases were generated with the following Python 3 script, which uses an approximation of the circumference of an ellipse devised by Ramanujan:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import math

a = 35 # semi-major axis
b = 40 # semi-minor axis
n = 4  # number of lanes
w = 5  # spacing between lanes (constant)

h = lambda a,b:(a-b)**2/(a+b)**2
lane_lengths = [math.pi*(a+b+w*i*2)*(1+3*h(a+w*i,b+w*i)/(10+math.sqrt(4-3*h(a+w*i,b+w*i)))) for i in range(n)]

print("{}, {}, {} -> {}".format(a, b, n, ', '.join([str(int(x-lane_lengths[0])) for x in lane_lengths[1:]])))
```

The approximation used is:

[image: ellipse circumference approximation]

Finally, here is a helpful diagram for understanding the calculations of the offsets:

[image: track]

Comment: I use Ramanujan's approximation like you did. Is that what we're supposed to do, or do you want us to evaluate the convergence of the infinite series?

Comment: @Adám You can do whatever it takes to get the required precision. The Ramanujan approximation is good for many values because its error is on the order of `h**5`, which is well under `0.01` for a wide range of values.

Comment: What good is a minimum accuracy when there is no bound on the input size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 43 bytes

```
UVFXY-nXY+WZn/3*©T4®-t+/>Z*žq*5DX+UY+V})¬-ï
```

**Explanation**

```
UV                                           # X = a, Y = b
  F                                   }      # n times do
   XY-n                                      # (a-b)^2
       XY+W                                  # Z = (a + b)
             /                               # divide (a-b)^2
           Zn                                # by (a+b)^2
              3*                             # multiply by 3
                ©                            # C = 3h
                       /                     # 3h divided by 
                 T                           # 10
                      +                      # +
                  4®-t                       # sqrt(4-3h)
                        >                    # increment
                         Z*žq*               # times (a + b)*pi
                              5DX+UY+V       # increase a and b by 5
                                       )     # wrap in list of circumferences
                                        ¬-   # divide by inner circumference
                                          ï  # floor
                                             # implicitly display
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=VVZGWFktblhZK1dabi8zKsKpVDTCri10Ky8-WirFvnEqNURYK1VZK1Z9KcKsLcOv&input=MTUKNDAKNw)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>103</s> 98 bytes

```haskell
c!d|h<-3*d*d/c/c=pi*c*(1+h/(10+sqrt(4-h)))
f a b n|x<-a-b=[floor$(a+b+10*w)!x-(a+b)!x|w<-[1..n-1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 45 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Prompts for *n*, then for *a* *b*. Requires `⎕IO←0` which is default on many systems.

```apl
⌊1↓(⊢-⊃)(○+×1+h÷10+.5*⍨4-h←3×2*⍨-÷+)⌿⎕∘.+5×⍳⎕
```

`⍳⎕` prompt for *n*, then give {0, 1, 2, ..., *n*−1)

`5×` multiply by five to get {0, 5, 10, ..., 5​*n*−5}

`⎕∘.+` prompt for *a* and *b*, then make an addition table:
  *a*, *a*+5, *a*+10, ... *a*+5​*n*−5
  *b*, *b*+5, *b*+10, ... *b*+5​*n*−5

`(`...`)⌿` apply the parenthesised function to each vertical pair, i.e.
  *f*(*a*, *b*), *f*(*a*+5, *b*+5), *f*(*a*+10, *b*+10), ..., *f*(*a*+5​*n*−5, *b*+5​*n*−5)
  where *f*(*x*, *y*) is*

> `○` pi times
>
> `+×` (*x* + *y*) times
>
> `1+` one plus
>
> `h÷` *h*(*x*, *y*) [the function *h* will be defined later] divided by
>
> `10+` ten plus
>
> `.5*⍨` the square-root of
>
> `4-` four minus
>
> `h←` *h*(*x*, *y*), which is
>
> `3×` three times
>
> `2*⍨` the square of
>
> `-÷` (*x* − *y*) divided by
>
> `+` *x* + *y*

`(⊢-⊃)` on the result of the function applied to each pair, subtract the value of the first result

`1↓` remove the first (zero)

`⌊` round down

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u230A1%u2193%28%u22A2-%u2283%29%28%u25CB+%D71+h%F710+.5*%u23684-h%u21903%D72*%u2368-%F7+%29%u233F%281%u2193%u2375%29%u2218.+5%D7%u2373%u2283%u233D%u2375%7D%A8%2820%2010%205%29%285%205%202%29%2815%2040%207%29%2835%2040%204%29&run)

---

*In procedural language:

`-÷+` find the fraction of the difference between and the sum of *x* and *y*

`2*⍨` square that fraction

`3×` multiply that square by three

`h←` assign that product to *h*

`4-` subtract that product from four

`.5*⍨` take the square-root of that difference

`10+` add ten to that square-root

`h÷` divide *h* by that sum

`1+` add one to that fraction

`+×` multiply that sum with the sum of *x* and *y*

`○` multiply that product by pi

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>168</s> 164 bytes

*Thanks to @Adám and @Mego for -2 bytes each*

```
from math import*
h=lambda a,b:3*(a-b)**2/(a+b)**2;C=lambda a,b:pi*(a+b)*(1+h(a,b)/(10+sqrt(4-h(a,b))))
f=lambda a,b,n:[int(C(a+i*5,b+i*5)-C(a,b))for i in range(n)]
```

A function `f` that takes input via argument and returns a list of lane offsets, including `0` for the innermost lane.

**How it works**

This uses Ramanujan's approxiamtion. We simply define functions `h` and `C` for calculating the parameter and circumference, then subtract the length of the innermost lane from the length of the current lane and floor, for all lanes.

[Try it on Ideone](http://ideone.com/ZxR4mt)

Comment: `sqrt(4-3*h(a,b))` is shorter as `(4-3*h(a,b))**.5`, and `floor` can be replaced by `int`. Doing both of those means you don't need to import `math`.

Comment: @Mego Thanks. Unless I'm being stupid, aren't those first two the same length? However, if the import statement gets removed, there is then the problem of defining pi.

Comment: By including the the `3*` in `h`, you should save two bytes.

Comment: I totally missed that you use `pi` You might be able to hardcode it with enough precision. And yeah, the first two are the same length - I meant without the import, of course! :P

Comment: @Adám Thanks for pointing that out.